ModuleError design choice
I'm curious to the design decisions for the ModuleError:
ModuleError {
    index: u8,
    error: [u8; 4],
    _,
}

This allows to describe an error within a range of 256 pallets and u32::max error index within that pallet. Why is there such a big difference?

In the early days, index and error used to be u8 ;)
However, there is support for nested errors and thus, it was increased to 4 bytes for the error type.

Is there a nested error in the polkadot sdk?

Maybe, I don't know for sure ;)
